# What is "Ubuntu Desktop USB" in tasksel?

Tags: server, 11.10, tasksel

What is Ubuntu Desktop USB tasksel alternative in ubuntu server 11.10 edition?

Comment: It is still there in the Ubuntu alternative network installer (`boot.img.gz`) of 12.04.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that snuck into the seeds that were used to build ISO's for Ubuntu 11.10, presumably fairly late, as it was not caught in the fairly comprehensive beta ISO testing.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/869796

The task option itself is not really useful, and shouldn't be seen there.

Comment: I'll use this in case someone ever wants an example for slow bug fixing in Ubuntu (11.10-14.04 = 2.5 years).